# Как запустить приложение на Spring WebMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Написал простой приложение на SpringMVC (без Spring Boot). Юнит-тесты для компонентов выполняются верно, но я не знаю, как запустить это приложение. В нем нет даже точки входа. Приложение состоит из RootConfig, WebConfig и двух контроллеров.

Как заставить все это работать? Предполагаю, что надо собрать war-файл и задеплоить приложение, например, на Jetty. Но это лишь предположение.

Comment: Все верно, вам нужно собрать war архив и задеплоить в Tomcat/Jetty etc...

Answer (score 0):

1) Есть документация на спрингИО.
2) Можно найти кучу примеров на гитхабе.
3) Программа запускается деплоем томката или джетти.
4) Затем идет работа через сервлет диспатчер - контроллер.
5) Подргужается ес-но из конфигов.
6) war в помнике прописать.

Недавний пример, месячной давности: [Spring-data-jpa](https://github.com/vinsler/Javarush.ru-Intership-2018-Spring-data-jpa)